# wxPython Object has no Attribute

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, attributeerror

Having issues changing label text from inside the Handler for the button (the spacing got all messed up when i pasted the code in but it is indented correctly)

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "Change Label\n")
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
    
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_pressed_handler, self.button)
    
    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("frame")
    
    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0)
        label = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "label_1")
        grid_sizer_1.Add(label, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.text, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button, 0, 0, 0)
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
    
    def button_pressed_handler(self, event):
        #Here is where i get the issue, how do i change the variable set in __do_layout?
        self.label.SetValue('changed')
        event.Skip()
```

The Error

AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

FULL TRACE minus the file location stuff:

line 34, in button_pressed_handler
self.label.SetValue('changed')
AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I noticed that in the ```self.label...``` line,  you haven't actually defined what ```self.label``` is in your code.

Comment: so instead of defining it under __do_layout and trying to interact with it via that i should just move it to __init__?

Comment: self.label is trying to reach label variable located under __do_layout

Comment: in `do_layout` you defined something called `label`, whilst in `button_pressed_handler` it has morphed into `self.label`. As it is, the original `label` is a local variable and not an instance variable. Change `label` in `do_layout` to `self.label` and change the sizer entry there as well to `self.label`.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick Rolf! post it as an answer so i can credit you if ya want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment:
in do_layout you defined something called label, whilst in button_pressed_handler it has morphed into self.label. As it is, the original label is a local variable and not an instance variable.

Change label in do_layout to self.label and change the sizer entry there as well to self.label.

You also need to change the update to `self.label.SetLabel('changed')` rather than `self.label.SetValue('changed')` as `StaticText` does not have a `SetValue` function.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "Change Label\n")
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
    
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_pressed_handler, self.button)
    
    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("frame")
    
    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0)
        #label = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "label_1")
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, "label_1")  # Change this
        #grid_sizer_1.Add(label, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.label, 0, 0, 0)                           # and change this
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.text, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button, 0, 0, 0)
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
    
    def button_pressed_handler(self, event):
        #Here is where i get the issue, how do i change the variable set in __do_layout?
        #self.label.SetValue('changed')
        self.label.SetLabel('changed')                                  # Change this to SetLabel
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()        
    app.MainLoop()
```